# Proving that $4^n = { {{2n+1} \choose {0}} + {{2n+1} \choose {1}} + \;...\; + {{2n+1} \choose {n}}}$

Tags: combinations, binomial-theorem

I was going through the section on Binomials in **Mathematics: Analyses and Approaches (IB)**. The author stated the expansion of $(1+x)^n$ as follows:

$$
(1+x)^n = { {{n} \choose {0}} + {{n} \choose {1}}x + {{n} \choose {2}}x^2 + \;...\; + {{n} \choose {n}}x^n}
$$

Then, he said that it could be used to prove the following relationships/equations:

$$
2^n = { {{n} \choose {0}} + {{n} \choose {1}} + {{n} \choose {2}} + \;...\; + {{n} \choose {n}}}
$$

$$
0^n = { {{n} \choose {0}} - {{n} \choose {1}} + {{n} \choose {2}} - {{n} \choose {3}} + \;...\; + (-1)^n{{n} \choose {n}}}
$$

I was able to derive these relationships on my own, but got stuck on the expansion of $4^n$, here is the result, based on the original expansion of $(1+x)^n$. Could someone please explain how to derive this?
$$
4^n = { {{2n+1} \choose {0}} + {{2n+1} \choose {1}} + \;...\; + {{2n+1} \choose {n}}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

using $\binom mr=\binom m{m-r}$

$$2S=2\sum_{r=0}^n\binom{2n+1}r =\sum_{r=0}^n \binom{2n+1}r+\sum_{r=0}^n\binom{2n+1}{2n+1-r} $$

Set $2n+1-r=p$
$$\sum_{r=0}^n\binom{2n+1}{2n+1-r}=\sum_{p=n+1}^{2n+1}\binom{2n+1}r $$

Consequently, 
$$2S=\sum_{r=0}^{2n}\binom{2n+1}r =(1+1)^{2n+1}$$

Comment: Why is:$$
\sum^n_{r=0} {{2n+1}\choose {2n+1-r}} = \sum^n_{r=0} {{2n+1} \choose {r}} 
$$ ?